# preg_replace - strip unwanted characters from string to return numeric value

Tags: php, regex, string

I hate regular expressions and I was hoping someone could help with a regualar expression to be used with preg_replace.

I want to strip unwanted characers from a string to return just a numeric value using preg_replace.

The string format could be as follows:

SOME TEXT £100

£100 SOME TEXT

SOME TEXT 100 SOME TEXT

Many thanks

Comment: So all these yield 100, right? What happens to `1abc00`?

Comment: Better yet - what about `£1.00`?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
$NumericVal = preg_replace("/[^0-9]/","",$TextVariable);
```

the ^ inside the [ ] means anything except the following

**Edit**
removed superfluous `+`

Comment: why not use `\D` out of curiosity... ? many answers on web use non-number rather than the built-in "not digit"

Comment: @nicorellius I wrote this real quick when I answered so didn't really think to use it is all, and haven't thought of it since to edit it to use \d. Though it is more readable for people without a good knowledge of the different regex options.

Answer (score 8):

```
$l = preg_replace("/[^A-Z0-9a-z\w ]/u", '', $l);
```

Works witch UTF-8, allow only A-Z a-z 0-9 łwóc... etc

Answer (score 0):

```
preg_replace('/[^0-9]/','',$text);
```

Comment: This gives `100` for Boltclock's example, too.

Comment: you need the + otherwise it will only replace the first non-number

Comment: No, that is partially true for `preg_match` but not for `preg_replace`. Just like any normal replace `preg_replace` replaces each occurence of a character that is `[^0-9]` with nothing and then continues its search with the next character.

Comment: @Patrick - if that was the case, it would fail on `acb100def` - the solution would be the `/g` flag. That's true for JavaScript, but not in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
preg_replace("/\D+/", "", "SOME TEXT £100")
```

You can also use `preg_match` to get the first number:

```
preg_match("/\d+/", "SOME TEXT £100", $matches);
$number = $matches[0];
```

Comment: Note that \D is the same as [^\d]